# $A^4 = I$ and A is $2024 \times 2024$. Why sum of eigenvalues is even?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

let $A$ be a $2024 \times 2024$ matrix of integer elements such that $A^4 = I$. Prove that $tr(A)$ is even. Also, prove such a matrix, exists. (possibly provide a way to build one).

---

I'm new to Linear algebra and I'm learning from Kunze, Hoffman in a self study manner.
here is my idea. I know that trace of the matrix, is sum of eigenvalues. I mean in characteristic polynomial of matrix, I do have $\sum \lambda_i = tr(A)$. But I don't know how to apply it on this problem and how to use the assumptions.

from $A^4 = I$, I can say the minimal polynomial of A is a divisor of $x^4-1 = 0$. so the eigen values could be $1,-1, i, -i$.
Also I can conclude that A is diagnosable as the minimal polynomial has distinct linear factors. But yet, now sure how to use any of these together

Any solution is appreciated. Simple ones are preferred. I'm not a pro in Linear Algebra :(

Comment: Sum of eigenvalues= Trace. $\sum \lambda_i =tr(A)$.            -Coeff of $x^{2023}=$Trace of A.

Comment: @MadhanKumar thanks. I just edited the question and added more clues (my knowledge. and need some hint on how to connect them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given condition implies that the only possible eigenvalues of $A$ are the roots of $x^4-1=0$, i.e., $1,-1$ and $\pm i$. Let the multiplicities of $1,-1$ and $i$ in the spectrum of $A$ be $p,q$ and $r$ respectively. Since non-real eigenvalues of $A$ must occur in conjugate pairs, the multiplicity of $-i$ is also $r$. Hence $p+q+2r=2024$. In turn, $\operatorname{tr}(A)=p-q=2024-2(q+r)$ is even.

Comment: could you tell me why $tr()=−$

Comment: @JacobMartina The trace is $p\times1+q\times-1+r\times i+r\times-i=p-q$.

Comment: AWESOME! and btw, any ideas on how to prove the existence of a 2024 by 2024 matrix A such that $A^4=I$?

Comment: @JacobMartina $I^4=I$ for instance.

Comment: any non-trivial example? I mean, if we want to prove such a matrix exists, is it sufficient to provide some example or we have to prove algebraically?

Comment: @JacobMartina Non-trivial example? Repeat $\pmatrix{0&1\\ -1&1\\ &&1\\ &&&-1}$ along the diagonal 506 times.

Comment: btw, in your solution, I guess you meant 2024 by 1024. I think there is a typo and true value for p+q+2r is 2024. as well as another 1024 appeared in the same line. am I right?

Comment: @JacobMartina Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: @JacobMartina *"any non-trivial example? I mean, if we want to prove such a matrix exists, is it sufficient to provide some example or we have to prove algebraically?"*: $A=I$ **is** an example. A trivial example, but it's enough to show *"such a matrix exists"*.

Comment: @JacobMartina I am sorry. There was a typo in the example above. The $(2,2)$-th entry should be $0$, not $1$, i.e., the first $2\times2$ submatrix should read $\pmatrix{0&1\\ -1&0}$ instead of $\pmatrix{0&1\\ -1&1}$.

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm 1$ or $\pm i$. Then
$$
\operatorname{trace}(A) = [\mu_A(+1) - \mu_A(-1)] + [\mu_A(+i) - \mu_A(-i)]i,
$$
where $\mu_A(\lambda)$ is the multiplicity of $\lambda$. Since the trace is real, we must have $\mu_A(+i) = \mu_A(-i)$. This implies that $\mu_A(+i) + \mu_A(-i)$ is even, and hence $\mu_A(+1) + \mu_A(-1)$ is also even, since the sum of all the multiplicities is $2024$.

To conclude, $\operatorname{trace}(A) = \mu_A(+1) - \mu_A(-1) = [\mu_A(+1) + \mu_A(-1)] - 2\mu_A(-1)$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

Not as good as the other solutions since this makes use of the assumption that the matrix has integer (rather than merely real) entries and it uses some more linear algebra facts, but I think the technique might be instructive:

Let $\tilde A$ be the reduction of $A$ mod $2$. Then $\tilde A$ has minimal polynomial dividing $t^4-1=(t-1)^4$, so its characteristic polynomial is $(t-1)^{2024}$ and the coefficient of $t^{2023}$ is $\operatorname{tr}(\tilde A)=-2024=0$, so $\operatorname{tr}(A)\equiv0\mod 2$.

Comment: Actually I think your answer is nicer.